# Error in variable declaration of Visual Basic Function

Tags: vb.net, function, variables, return

I'm new to coding, just switched my major from EE to IT - having trouble with Visual Basic Functions.  I think my error is somewhere in variable declaring on the functions but I'm not entirely sure.  The program is supposed to multiply the days spent at a Hospital by a constant I have declared = 350, and add all the miscellaneous charges to that number, but I return 0.  Can anyone help me spot the error?

Visual Basic Code:

```
Const decStay_Rate As Decimal = 350

    Private decLength As Integer
    Private decMedication As Decimal
    Private decSurgical As Decimal
    Private decLab As Decimal
    Private decPhysical As Decimal
    Private decTotalStayPrice As Decimal
    Private decTotalMiscCharges As Decimal

    Private decTotal As Decimal
    Dim decStay As Decimal


    Function validateInputField() As Boolean
        If Not Decimal.TryParse(txtLength.Text, decLength) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Stay Length must be numeric")
        End If
        If Not Decimal.TryParse(txtMedication.Text, decMedication) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Medication cost must be numeric")
        End If
        If Not Decimal.TryParse(txtSurgical.Text, decSurgical) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Surgical cost must be numeric")
        End If
        If Not Decimal.TryParse(txtLabFees.Text, decLab) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Lab fees must be numeric")
        End If
        If Not Decimal.TryParse(txtPhysicalRehab.Text, decPhysical) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Physical Rehab cost must be numeric")
        End If

        Return True
    End Function

    Function CalcStayCharges(ByVal decLength As Decimal) As Decimal
        Dim decTotalStayPrice As Decimal
        decTotalStayPrice = decLength * decStay_Rate
        Return decTotalStayPrice
    End Function

    Function CalcMiscCharges(ByVal decmedication As Decimal, ByVal decsurgical As Decimal, ByVal decLab As Decimal, ByVal decPhysical As Decimal) As Decimal
        Dim decTotalMiscCharges As Decimal
        decTotalMiscCharges = decmedication + decsurgical + decLab + decPhysical
        Return decTotalMiscCharges
    End Function

    Private Function CalcTotalCharges(ByVal decTotalStayPrice As Decimal, ByVal decTotalMiscCharges As Decimal) As Decimal
        Dim decTotalCharge As Decimal
        decTotalCharge = decTotalStayPrice + decTotalMiscCharges
        Return decTotalCharge
    End Function
    Private Sub btnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click

        txtLabFees.Text = String.Empty
        txtLength.Text = String.Empty
        txtMedication.Text = String.Empty
        txtPhysicalRehab.Text = String.Empty
        txtSurgical.Text = String.Empty

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnCalc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalc.Click
        Dim decTotal As Decimal

        lblOutput.Text = String.Empty
        If validateInputField() Then
            decTotal = CalcTotalCharges(decTotalStayPrice, decTotalMiscCharges)

            lblOutput.Text = decTotal.ToString("c")
        End If
    End Sub
```

Thanks,
Eric

Comment: Welcome Eric. As you could see in the vba tag description, VBA and VB.NET are not equivalent.

Comment: Thank you, I corrected that

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the code (click in the left margin, get a red spot) then step through. You can hover your mouse pointer over the variables to get their current values.

Comment: Okay, that sounds pretty useful.  Thanks for giving me direction rather than just solving it for me.  I'll be working with this later tonight again

Comment: The answer is fine, I'm giving it a try rn.  I just wanted a means to check my errors in the future as well.  Why did that get downvoted?

Comment: Okay, so I had the variable declared at the top = 0 and thought I was pulling from the variable value within the method but was actually pulling the 0 value.  I need to brush up on scope and variable declaration.  Thank you very much for the help as well as pointing out where my weaknesses are.  I will work towards making my variable declarations less sloppily.  Take Care Jinx

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't need `Decimal.TryParse(txtLength.Text, decLength)` to check if it's numeric. You could use [IsNumeric](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6cd3f6w1(v=vs.90).aspx) so `IsNumeric(txtLength.Text)`. `Decimal.TryParse` will assign the value from `txtLength.Text` to `decLength` if successful however you don't need to do this in your case.

I would change the method `validateInputField` to:

```
Function validateInputField() As Boolean
    If Not IsNumeric(txtLength.Text) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Stay Length must be numeric")
        Return False
    End If
    If Not IsNumeric(txtMedication.Text) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Medication cost must be numeric")
        Return False
    End If
    If Not IsNumeric(txtSurgical.Text) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Surgical cost must be numeric")
        Return False
    End If
    If Not IsNumeric(txtLabFees.Text) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Lab fees must be numeric")
        Return False
    End If
    If Not IsNumeric(txtPhysicalRehab.Text) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Physical Rehab cost must be numeric")
        Return False
    End If

    Return True
End Function
```

I'd remove all of these as they are causing you confusion:

```
Private decLength As Integer
Private decMedication As Decimal
Private decSurgical As Decimal
Private decLab As Decimal
Private decPhysical As Decimal
Private decTotalStayPrice As Decimal
Private decTotalMiscCharges As Decimal

Private decTotal As Decimal
Dim decStay As Decimal
```

You would then want to pass the right values to the method `CalcTotalCharges`:

```
decTotal = CalcTotalCharges(value1, value2)
```

In a roundabout way you are probably after:

```
Private Sub btnCalc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalc.Click
    Dim decTotal As Decimal

    lblOutput.Text = ""
    If validateInputField() Then
        decTotal = CalcTotalCharges(CalcStayCharges(CDec(txtLength.Text)), CalcMiscCharges(CDec(txtMedication.Text), CDec(txtSurgical.Text), CDec(txtLabFees.Text), CDec(txtPhysicalRehab.Text)))

        lblOutput.Text = decTotal.ToString("c")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: That fixed it, thank you.  The error was in me forgetting to return false on the boolean function and my code on the button

Comment: Not a problem. Glad you've sorted it.